# What's the difference between "licensing" and "licensure?"

Tags: word-choice, differences, american-english

On the new [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), we field questions about professional engineering registration. The tag categorizing these questions is "licensure" and I usually find myself referring to the topic by that word but there are times when I feel like I should use "licensing" instead. I feel like the two words carry slightly different implications but I have trouble identifying the specific way in which they are different.

For example, I much prefer "licensure" here:

> This question concerns professional *licensure*.

but it does not work here:

> The Board for Professional Engineers is a *licensing* body.

and either seems to work here:

> The organization deals with *professional licensing issues*.
>
> The organization deals with *issues of professional licensure*.

Are these words synonyms? They don't seem to be equivalent in every formulation; how can I decide which is more appropriate for a given sentence?

I don't think this is directly related to [the license/licence distinction](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2882/88259).

Answer (score 4):

In each of your examples *licensing* is used as an adjective, while *licensure* is used as a noun.

*[Licensure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/licensure)*:

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN] chiefly North American
>
> The granting of a license, especially to carry out a trade or
>   profession.

The suffix [-ure](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ure&searchmode=none) creates an abstract active noun:

> suffix forming abstract nouns of action,
>
> from Old French -ure,
>
> from
>   Latin -ura, an ending of fem. nouns
>   denoting employment or result.

*Licensing* is the progressive form of license, used as a verb, noun or an adjective, depending on the context:

> - All the *[progressive conjugations](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/license.html)* are verbal uses of *licensing*
>
> *The Board for Professional Engineers has been **licensing** engineers for 4 decades.*
>
> - As a [present participle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/present_participle), *licensing* is used as an adjective.
>
> *The Board for Professional Engineers is a **licensing** body.*
>
> - As a [gerund](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/gerundterm.htm), *licensing* is used as a noun.
>
> *The Board for Professional Engineers arranges the **licensing** of engineers.*

Comment: Suppose I remove "issues" and "issues of" in the third example: "The organization deals with professional [licensing|licensure]." Isn't that a legitimate construction with the words being nouns in either case?

Comment: Still *profession* is an adjective and *licensure* is the object of the preposition with (rather than of).